# Getting data from Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres, I've this table:

```
id | fieldname | value
----------------------
1  | price     | 10000
```

and

```
id | dyn_field | dyn_value
--------------------------
1  | bathroom  | 2
2  | bedroom   | 4
```

and I would like to get the following output

```
field     | value
---------------------
price     | 10000
bathroom  | 2
bedroom   | 4
```

What query can be used for get these output,.?
thanks,.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT fieldname AS field, value AS value
FROM tableOne
UNION ALL
SELECT dyn_field AS field, dyn_value AS value
FROM tableTwo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT fieldname, value FROM this_table
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT dyn_field, dyn_value FROM and_table
```

(You didn't specify the table names, so I made them up).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT fieldname as field, value 
FROM table1 
UNION select dyn_field as field, dyn_value as value 
FROM table2
```